# Why does len on x/net/html Token().Attr return a non-zero value for an empty slice here?

Tags: go, slice, tokenize

I am using the built-in `html` library in Golang.
Here's the code to reproduce the issue:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "golang.org/x/net/html"
)

const url = "https://google.com"

func main() {
    resp, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    if resp.StatusCode != 200 {
        log.Fatalf("Status code error: %d %s", resp.StatusCode, resp.Status)
    }

    h := html.NewTokenizer(resp.Body)

    for {
        if h.Next() == html.ErrorToken {
            break
        }

        l := len(h.Token().Attr)

        if l != 0 {
            fmt.Println("=======")
            fmt.Println("Length", l) // greater than 0
            fmt.Println("Attr", h.Token().Attr) // empty all the times
        }
    }
}
```

Here's what the output looks like

```
=======
Length 2
Attr []
typeof Attr []html.Attribute
=======
Length 8
Attr []
typeof Attr []html.Attribute
=======
Length 1
Attr []
typeof Attr []html.Attribute
=======
Length 1
Attr []
typeof Attr []html.Attribute
```

go version

```
go version go1.17.7 linux/amd64
```

Why does Go think the length of `h.Token().Attr` is non-zero here when the `h.Token().Attr` is empty?

P.S.: saving the output of `h.Token().Attr` and using it for `len` and printing the contents makes everything work fine

Code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "golang.org/x/net/html"
)

const url = "https://google.com"

func main() {
    resp, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    if resp.StatusCode != 200 {
        log.Fatalf("Status code error: %d %s", resp.StatusCode, resp.Status)
    }

    h := html.NewTokenizer(resp.Body)

    for {
        if h.Next() == html.ErrorToken {
            break
        }

        attrs := h.Token().Attr // save the output here and use it everywhere else
        l := len(attrs)

        if l != 0 {
            fmt.Println("=======")
            fmt.Println("Length", l)
            fmt.Println("Attr", attrs)
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
Length 3
Attr [{ value AJiK0e8AAAAAYtZT7PXDBRBC2BJawIxezEfmIL6Aw5Uy} { name iflsig} { type hidden}]
=======
Length 4
Attr [{ class fl sblc} { align left} { nowrap } { width 25%}]
=======
Length 1
Attr [{ href /advanced_search?hl=en-IN&authuser=0}]
=======
Length 4
Attr [{ id gbv} { name gbv} { type hidden} { value 1}]
```

Comment: Obviously, `Token()` returns a different token every time it's called. :-)

Comment: That explains everything haha. Thank you!

Comment: @oakad, your comment answers my question. If you can include it as an Answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Not exactly either. It doesn't advance, it doesn't return the *next* token, it just returns something kind of invalid. The docs are specific about the sequence of method calls that you can make and get valid results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tokenizer has a kind of funny interface, and you aren't allowed to call `Token()` more than once between calls to `Next()`. As the doc says:

> In EBNF notation, the valid call sequence per token is:
> `Next {Raw} [ Token | Text | TagName {TagAttr} ]`

Which is to say: after calling `Next()` you may call `Raw()` zero or more times; then you can *either*:

- Call `Token()` once,
- Call `Text()` once,
- Call `TagName()` once followed by `TagAttr()` zero or more times (presumably, either not at all because you don't care about the attributes, or enough times to retrieve all of the attributes).
- Or do nothing (maybe you're skipping tokens).

The results of calling things out of sequence are undefined, because the methods modify internal state — they're not pure accessors. In your first snippet you call `Token()` multiple times between calls to `Next()`, so the result is invalid. All of the attributes are consumed by the first call, and aren't returned by the later ones.

Answer (score 0):

The `(*Tokenizer).Token()` returns a new Token everytime which has a new []Attr again, In the `.Token()` [here](https://cs.opensource.google/go/x/net/+/master:html/token.go;l=1139) the tokenizer in the next call has the start and end are the same number on line 1145 there, so it doesn't go in [this loop](https://cs.opensource.google/go/x/net/+/master:html/token.go;l=1178), so the Attr will be empty next time.

Answer (score -1):

It's not empty, you just need to loop over it and view the values.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"

    "golang.org/x/net/html"
)

func main() {
    body := `
<html lang="en">
<body onload="fool()">
</body>
</html>
`
    h := html.NewTokenizer(strings.NewReader(body))

    for {
        if h.Next() == html.ErrorToken {
            break
        }

        attr := h.Token().Attr
        l := len(attr)

        if l != 0 {
            fmt.Println("=======")
            fmt.Println("Length", l) // greater than 0
            for i, a := range attr {
                fmt.Printf("Attr %d %v\n", i, a)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Playground: https://go.dev/play/p/lzEdppsURl0

Comment: Looks like I misunderstood how `h.Token()` works. It returns a new value every time I call it.